Unique solution of the eikonal
I am exploring the Eikonal equation, defined as:
$$
\|\nabla u(x)\| = 1\;  and \; u(x) > 0\quad \text{for } x \in A \subset \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
for some open set $A$, with the boundary condition:
$$
u(x) = 0 \quad \text{on } \partial A.
$$
From my understanding, the solution to this equation is generally the distance function. However, in certain cases, I observe that multiple solutions seem to exist.
For example, if $ A = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x_s\} $ for some point $ x_s $, the function $ f(x) = \|x - x_s\| $ is the expected distance function. But if I consider a different function based on a projection, such as:
$$
\tilde{f}(x) = \sqrt{(x_i - x_{s,i})^2} = |x_i - x_{s,i}|,
$$
this function also satisfies $ \|\nabla \tilde{f}\| = 1 $.
What additional conditions should be imposed on the Eikonal equation to guarantee the uniqueness of its solution, I've seen some definitions about viscosity solutions but couldn't understand how they are applied here.

Viscosity solutions are practically designed to solve this problem. The wiki page even uses your equation as an example. Did this not answer your question?

Indeed, the example you provided, based on projection, is not a viscosity solution of the eikonal equation, though it is an "almost everywhere" solution, meaning it satisfies the equation at all points of differentiability. Almost everywhere solutions are generally not unique (usually there are infinitely many), and the viscosity solution selects the "physically correct" solution in essentially all situations (it selects the distance function here). You should read up on wikipedia or other sources about viscosity solutions and then ask again.

Also here: https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~jwcalder/viscosity_solutions.pdf
